# Auto-generate screenshots using latitude/longitude information without Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I've been working on a project where we need to generate map images based on latitude/longitude inputs.  Say, something like the image below:

http://lawyertechreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/map-screenshot-notes.jpg

Not perfect but kind of what we're going for.  Basically we need a screenshot of the location and its surrounding area, based on latitude/longitude info multiplied by a few hundred thousand.  Google Maps offers this service in their API, but it's against their TOS to use it in such volume so we've been trying to find another way to do it.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any alternatives, services or software that might be able to do the above?

Comment: Have you thought about downloading OpenStreetMaps data? https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data

Comment: if you're projected requests will surpass whatever google static maps api offers, then you can use either OSM tile service or look for another provider of imaginery. Faking google maps navigation just to capture their tiles sounds like cheating to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) script to do this. It acts as a headless browser, so you could just create a normal/blank web page that just loaded a map with the lat/lon, set the size of the map you want in the page (or pass it as url params from phantomjs and parse with js on the web page to change the size auto-magically) and take a screen shot of just that dom element with the "visible" map. I'm not sure if this would violate their ToS, but it's using the map api (not the map images API). [Google Map API limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage) :

> If your site or application generates 25 000 map loads or more each day, for more than 90 consecutive days, we’ll get in touch with you to talk about payment. Don’t worry, if you go over the limits, we won’t immediately shut off your API access or display error messages on your site.

Check out this script for inspiration: ["PhantomJS: Capturing single dom elements as png files"](https://gist.github.com/n1k0/1501173)